# Primary key and entity id difference

Tags: database

I am little confused about the primary key and ID in the database table.

I want to identify the rows in my table based on some logical id like pay_xyz123, pay_xyz124 , order_xyz etc. If I use these format as pk which is a string would it affect the performance.

Or should I use auto-increment numbers as pk and the id's like pay_xyz123 as unique key. What would be the best approach

Edit: the logical id's can be a long string say 15 characters

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer having synthetic ids (i.e. auto-increment/serial/identity column) for such tables.  This has some advantages:

- You can update the entity id easily, because it is an attribute and not used for foreign key references.
- Integers are (slightly) more efficient for indexing purposes.
- The a synthetic id hides entity name information in the tables that reference the key.

It also allows things like soft deletes -- where deletion is by a flag rather than removing the row -- with an insert using the same id.  Of course, you have to adjust the uniqueness constraint to allow this.

Of course, there is a slight overhead to storing the auto-incremented key.  This increases the size of the base table.  Usually string names are longer (as in your example), so this is more than offset by having a reduced length in the rows that refer to the entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your key for foreign keys into other tables, I personally would use a numeric auto increment id. You can still place an alternate index on your logical key and even a unique constraint on the logical key if the business rules warrant.

The downside, in my opinion, of using the logical key for foreign keys, is that if the logical key changes, then you have to update all of the foreign keys.